# celerra checkpoint for a share paused

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, celerra

This morning when i tried to check the checkpoint feature-I stumbled upon this...

> Id Name                 State      Next Run                       Description

21 Daily_Patient        **Paused**     Wed Nov 17 01:05:00 EST 2010
11 UFS11_daily           Active     Tue Nov 16 23:02:00 EST 2010                     UFS11_Weekly             Active     Sun Nov 21 05:32:00 EST 2010 <

nas_ckpt_schedule -list

> Id                     = 21
>
> Name= Daily_Patient                                                                  ,Description = Snap_Patient_daily,
> Tasks  = Checkpoint Daily_Patient on filesystem id=143
> Next Run               = Wed Nov 17 01:05:00 EST 2010
> State                  = Paused
> Recurrence             = every 1 weeks
> Start On               = Fri Nov 20 14:04:12 EST 2009
> End On                 =
> At Which Times         = 01:05
> On Which Days of Week  = Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri

Does this mean the checkpoint feature is disabled for the share because of SavVol full or something? i am unable to understand this..

Do i get an option in CLI to check for the SavVol used? As far as i know, this shouldn't be happening since we use AVM feature and have HWM set up ,SavVol is auto expandable in this case>>  Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `fs_ckpt -list -all`, to check the SavVol usage, basically when the SavVol is full, the newly created ckpts overwrite the oldest one in the SavVol.

If you find the SvVol over utilized, you can extend it using `nas_fs` command

`nas_fs -xtend <ckpt name> -size=10G` [just an example] not sure about the exact syntax
run `nas_fs` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to display the command parameters and usage.